# For-loop with else condition runs even though the condition is true

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, input

Beginner question! The `else` condition run even though the `for` statement is `True` and prints out the text message that declares that it hasn't found the key. Since the statement is `True` it also gives me the information I want, problem is that it runs `else` even though `for` is `True`.

```py
input_namn = input("Ange ett namn: ")               
for key in rooms_with:                          
    if input_namn in rooms_with[key]:
        print (input_namn + "\ndelar rum med \n" + key)
else: 
    print ("\nPersonen du angav är inte en del av föreningen\n")
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: what are the values in rooms_with ?

Answer (score 2):

Your **indentation** is bad on the `else` clause.

Since it's on the same level as the `for` loop, the `else` belongs to the `for` loop and not the `if` statement.

Just **indent** the `else` clause on the same level as the `if` like below:

```py
input_namn = input("Ange ett namn: ")
for key in rooms_with:
    if input_namn in rooms_with[key]:
        print (input_namn + "\ndelar rum med \n" + key)
    else: # This is indented correctly
        print ("\nPersonen du angav är inte en del av föreningen\n")
```

---

#### What happens when the `else` belongs to the `for` loop ?

[Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) says:

> Loop statements may have an `else` clause; it is executed when the loop terminates through exhaustion of the iterable (with `for`) or when the condition becomes false (with `while`), but not when the loop is terminated by a `break` statement.

Basically, at the end of the loop the `else` block is executed except if the loops was stopped by a `break` statement.

And since there was no `break` statement in your loop, your `else` branch was executed.